# Remove bottom padding in table in cfdocument

Tags: html-table, coldfusion, cfdocument

I use `cfdocument` and I need to remove `bottom-padding` from my table.

```
<cfdocument format="pdf">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        table {
          font-family: arial, sans-serif;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          width: 100%;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h2>HTML Table</h2>
      <table bgcolor="red">
        <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
          <td>Maria Anders</td>
          <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ernst Handel</td>
          <td>Roland Mendel</td>
          <td>Austria</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Island Trading</td>
          <td>Helen Bennett</td>
          <td>UK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
          <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;" cellspacing="0">Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
          <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;" cellspacing="0">Giovanni Rovelli</td>
          <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;" cellspacing="0">Italy</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
</cfdocument>
```

I need to remove the bottom padding (yellow vertical line)

[image]

I use `padding-bottom: 0px;` but didn't worked. There is `cellspacing="0"` but it will affect entire table.

cffiddle : https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=7b8c6141-8bac-42f5-a653-71ddce64c554/fe42c362-17cb-4810-b532-64e11d98685a/c885261b-341d-4ea2-b6d8-3c55687094ec.cfm

Comment: Will `cellspacing="0"` with custom padding for other cells work for you?

Comment: that's what my solution right now.

Comment: Which verson of ColdFusion

Comment: I use ColdFusion 2016